# Karma/Jasmine: Unable to detect changes for @Input property using detectChanges()

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am trying to change the @Input property of the component and based on the new property, trying to check if the button is enabled/disabled. Referring the code [here](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/components/)

I am following the exact procedure which is described at this link, but not working. I am changing the value, using detectChanges() but it is not giving result as expected.

HTML:

```
<form>
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="email"
           #email>
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password"
           #password>
    <button type="button" 
            (click)="login(email.value, password.value)"
            [disabled]="!enabled">Login
    </button>
  </form>
```

Component:

```
@Input() enabled = true;
```

Spec:

```
describe('testing app component', () => {
  let component;
  let service;
  let fixture;
  let element;
  let atag;
  let loginEl;
  let passwordEl;
  let submitEl;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        AppService
      ]
    }).compileComponents();

    // create component fixture
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);

    // get component's instance for testing
    component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;

    // getting service instance from tets bed
    service = TestBed.get(AppService);

    // getting button element
    fixture.detectChanges();
    element = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button'));
    atag = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('a'));

    submitEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button'));
    loginEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input[type=email]'));
    passwordEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input[type=password]'));
  });

  it('testing input property: @Input enabled', () => {
    expect(component.enabled).toBe(true);
    expect(submitEl.nativeElement.disabled).toBeFalsy();
    component.enabled = false;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(submitEl.nativeElement.disabled).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

But this spec throws an error: `Error: Expected false to be truthy.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** :

The way you are creating the component is also incorrect. It has to be

```
component = fixture.componentInstance;
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-test-unit?file=app%2Fhello.component.spec.ts)

**Original**

You should fetch your `dom` elements once again after the view is updated (i,e after `detectChanges()` is called). If you don't then your tests are verified against the view that was present before updating.

```
submitEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button'));
```

- test spec

```
it('testing input property: @Input enabled', () => {
    expect(component.enabled).toBe(true);
    expect(submitEl.nativeElement.disabled).toBeFalsy();
    component.enabled = false;
    fixture.detectChanges();

     // fetch dom element again
    submitEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button'));
    expect(submitEl.nativeElement.disabled).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Comment: Does your first two expects pass? `expect(component.enabled).toBe(true);
    expect(submitEl.nativeElement.disabled).toBeFalsy();`

Comment: And the way you are creating the component is also wrong. It has to be `component = fixture.componentInstance;`

Comment: Yes, other expects are passing. And, I changed the way I created the fixture, but still the error is same. It's not working. I am unable to replicate the same in online editors, so is there any way I can share the code?

Comment: So, in online editor your test case passes? If so, then simply rerun your test cases and verify.

Comment: Check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-test-unit?file=app%2Fhello.component.spec.ts It does work

Comment: thanks a lot.. don't know why they don't run in my local in visual studio code using ng test --code-coverage.

Comment: Just restart everything and serve again.

Comment: Manually calling ngOnChanges() as per https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6235#issuecomment-236281930 worked for me.